# How to send message from ios app with message body and recipients number disabled for editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, sms

I know that we can use `MFMessageComposeViewController` to send message from iOS app. However, I have a requirement of disabling recipient number and message body to remain disabled for editing by user. User can either cancel the message or send it from the `viewcontroller`. I did not find any property or method for this requirement.

Is this achievable?

Comment: You could hack it, but it is likely that Apple would reject your app if this is discovered.

Comment: @Avi .. How can I hack it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, 
Editing or manipulating iOS native controls is not possible. You can reroute it with the data in `MFMessageComposeViewController`, but you cannot customise it in any way.